# How to extract data from transect located in a single shp file

Tags: r, gis

I have 7 separate transect lines in one shapefile. Is there a way to extract data from to select an individual transect line from the file and extract and use it as a way to extract data from a raster file

I have currently used this function in R

```
 extract(raster, transect line.shp )
```

but this extracts the data from all 7 transects at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal reproducible example that I copied from ?raster::extract.

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
cds1 <- rbind(c(-50,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-10,-25))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,20), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55))
lines <- spLines(cds1, cds2)
```

Extract for all lines

```
extract(r, lines)
[[1]]
 [1] 126 127 161 162 163 164 196 197 200 201 231 232 237 266 267 273 274 302 310
[20] 311 338 346 381 382 414 417 450 451 452 453 487 488

[[2]]
 [1] 139 140 141 174 175 177 208 209 210 213 243 244 249 250 279 286 322 358 359
[20] 394 429 430 465 501 537
```

To extract for a single line, subset the SpatialLines object. For example, to get the first line:

```
extract(r, lines[1,])
[[1]]
 [1] 126 127 161 162 163 164 196 197 200 201 231 232 237 266 267 273 274 302 310
[20] 311 338 346 381 382 414 417 450 451 452 453 487 488
```